# How to create "ENDSWITH" predicate for SwiftData @Query?

Tags: ios, swift, predicate, swift-data, swift-data-modelcontext

I can create all kinds of predicates fine, but I'm not sure what can I use for implement "ENDSWITH"?

```
extension Filter {

    var predicate: Predicate<WordModel>? {
        switch self {
        case .all:
            .none
        case .lettersContaining(let string):
            #Predicate<WordModel> {
                $0.letters.localizedStandardContains(string)
            }
        case .lettersStartingWith(let string):
            #Predicate<WordModel> {
                $0.letters.starts(with: string)
            }
        case .lettersEndingWith(let string):
            #Predicate<WordModel> {
                $0.letters.hasSuffix(string) // 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code says "The hasSuffix(_:) function is not supported in this predicate".

I can see in the docs (at [PredicateExpressions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/predicateexpressions)) that the predicate closure is a builder expression that can contain a fixed set of expressions, I'm just not sure what to use for my use-case.

What do you use to create "ENDSWITH" predicates for a SwiftData `@Query`?

Comment: In theory I could reverse both `letters` and `string` and use `starts(with:)`, but I'm pretty sure there must be something better.

Comment: Hmmmm I had a look through at the source code for the `#Predicate` macro, which lists [all the functions it looks for](https://github.com/apple/swift-foundation/blob/c4fa869c60aa5d073cd9f363dfdbb5ad56a78277/Sources/FoundationMacros/PredicateMacro.swift#L27-L41). Nothing exists for `ends(with:)`, `hasSuffix`, etc.

Comment: To be honest, I think Apple just *forgot* to implement this.

Comment: @Sweeper Part of the issue is that these predicates operate on `Sequence` (not `Collection`), so it's not possible to ask questions about the length, last index, iterate backwards, etc. Also interesting, there's nothing like `hasSuffix` for `Collection`.

Comment: @Alexander I understand. But things like length and last index can surely be accessed, right? They are just key paths.

Comment: @Sweeper Not for a Predicate that handles any arbitrary Sequence value. Say you applied the predicate to `1...`. There is no length or last index.

Comment: @Alexander Of course, there wouldn't be a `count` or `endIndex` key path on an arbitrary `Sequence` in the first place. But for types that do have these, you can get them. It's just key paths.

Comment: Anything that's inside a predicate must be able to be expressed using SQL, either directly or perhaps more likely as a Core Data compatible NSPredicate so I guess it might take some time to support all functions available in swift.

Comment: I'm migrating from Core Data, where `NSPredicate(format: "letters ENDSWITH[cd] %@", string)` works fine.

Comment: Now that I think of, can't we use NSPredicate somehow to create a `@Query`? I'm making them in the view initializer anyway.

Comment: No there is no way to use NSPredicate right now and I am doubtful Apple will introduce that functionality but who knows.

Comment: We had a similar situation when SwiftUI introduced, yet we always had the option to fallback to UIKit if needed. This just feels such a brickwall-ee thing that we cannot extend `PredicateExpression`.

Comment: ️ Side-note: SwiftData is keep interrupting the development flow with so many trial-and-error, guesswork kind of thing (not to mention the zero error message, zero documentation crashes with some relationship configurations). I understand that it is here to Swiftify CoreData, but in terms of developer experience is like Objective-C is here again. It breaks down as soon as people actually want to build filtering functionality, not just WWDC sample apps.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, this definitely doesn't exist, **and it can't be implemented manually, either.**

The rest of my answer below shows my attempt at that, which ultimately hits a show-stopping limitation, right at the end.

---

It's possible to implement a predicate that supports matching with `ends(with:)` behaviour, but with pretty severe limitations.

Firstly, you can see the list of all the functions the `#Predicate` macro supports, [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-foundation/blob/c4fa869/Sources/FoundationMacros/PredicateMacro.swift#L27-L41).

```swift
private var _knownSupportedFunctions: Set<FunctionStructure> = [
    FunctionStructure("contains", arguments: [.unlabeled]),
    FunctionStructure("contains", arguments: [.closure(labeled: "where")]),
    FunctionStructure("allSatisfy", arguments: [.closure(labeled: nil)]),
    FunctionStructure("flatMap", arguments: [.closure(labeled: nil)]),
    FunctionStructure("filter", arguments: [.closure(labeled: nil)]),
    FunctionStructure("subscript", arguments: [.unlabeled]),
    FunctionStructure("subscript", arguments: [.unlabeled, "default"]),
    FunctionStructure("starts", arguments: ["with"]),
    FunctionStructure("min", arguments: []),
    FunctionStructure("max", arguments: []),
    FunctionStructure("localizedStandardContains", arguments: [.unlabeled]),
    FunctionStructure("localizedCompare", arguments: [.unlabeled]),
    FunctionStructure("caseInsensitiveCompare", arguments: [.unlabeled])
]
```

Even if you hand-roll your own custom predicate type that matches items using `ends(with:)` behaviour, you won't be able register it in this `_knownSupportedFunctions`, so you won't be able to use it with the `#Predicate` macro. So usages of the predicate have to be hand-rolled, and won't be pretty.

Also, the resulting hand-rolled predicate can only be used with pure Swift code, but not with e.g. SwiftData or CoreData, because it's not possible to define how this custom predicate should lower to `NSPredicate` (which is what is used to ultimately lower it to SQL).

## Step 1 - Implementing an `ends(with:)` function

To my surprise, there's no `ends(with:)` counterpart to [`starts(with:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d6f9401/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L235-L252).

We can implement one:

```swift
extension BidirectionalCollection where Element: Equatable {
  // Adapted from https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d6f9401/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L281-L286
  @inlinable
  public func ends<PossibleSuffix: BidirectionalCollection>(
    with possibleSuffix: PossibleSuffix
  ) -> Bool where PossibleSuffix.Element == Element {
    return self.ends(with: possibleSuffix, by: ==)
  }

  // Adapted from https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d6f9401/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L235-L252
  @inlinable
  public func ends<PossibleSuffix: BidirectionalCollection>(
    with possibleSuffix: PossibleSuffix,
    by areEquivalent: (Element, PossibleSuffix.Element) throws -> Bool
  ) rethrows -> Bool {
    var possibleSuffixIterator = possibleSuffix.reversed().makeIterator()
    for e0 in self.reversed() {
      if let e1 = possibleSuffixIterator.next() {
        if try !areEquivalent(e0, e1) {
          return false
        }
      }
      else {
        return true
      }
    }
    return possibleSuffixIterator.next() == nil
  }
}
```

## Step 2 - Creating a new `PredicateExpression`

Next, we'll need to add the various predicate types needed to wrap it. I wrote all these by copying the `SequenceStartsWith`-related code and adapting it as needed.

```swift
extension PredicateExpressions {
  // Adapted from `SequenceStartsWith`
  // https://github.com/apple/swift-foundation/blob/c4fa869/Sources/FoundationEssentials/Predicate/Expressions/Sequence.swift#L101-L124
  public struct CollectionEndsWith<
  Base : PredicateExpression,
  Suffix : PredicateExpression
  > : PredicateExpression
  where
  Base.Output : BidirectionalCollection,
  Suffix.Output : BidirectionalCollection,
  Base.Output.Element == Suffix.Output.Element,
  Base.Output.Element : Equatable
  {
    public typealias Output = Bool
    
    public let base: Base
    public let suffix: Suffix
    
    public init(base: Base, suffix: Suffix) {
      self.base = base
      self.suffix = suffix
    }
    
    public func evaluate(_ bindings: PredicateBindings) throws -> Bool {
      try base.evaluate(bindings).ends(with: try suffix.evaluate(bindings))
    }
  }
}

// Adapted from https://github.com/apple/swift-foundation/blob/c4fa869/Sources/FoundationEssentials/Predicate/Expressions/Sequence.swift#L226-L239
@available(FoundationPredicate 0.1, *)
extension PredicateExpressions.CollectionEndsWith : Codable where Base : Codable, Suffix : Codable {
  public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
    try container.encode(base)
    try container.encode(suffix)
  }
  
  public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
    self.base = try container.decode(Base.self)
    self.suffix = try container.decode(Suffix.self)
  }
}

// Adapted from https://github.com/apple/swift-foundation/blob/c4fa869/Sources/FoundationEssentials/Predicate/Expressions/Sequence.swift#L174-L175
@available(FoundationPredicate 0.1, *)
extension PredicateExpressions.CollectionEndsWith : StandardPredicateExpression where Base : StandardPredicateExpression, Suffix : StandardPredicateExpression {}

extension PredicateExpressions {
  // Adapted from `build_starts`
  // https://github.com/apple/swift-foundation/blob/c4fa869/Sources/FoundationEssentials/Predicate/Expressions/Sequence.swift#L139
  public static func build_ends<Base, Suffix>(_ base: Base, with suffix: Suffix) -> CollectionEndsWith<Base, Suffix> {
    CollectionEndsWith(base: base, suffix: suffix)
  }
}
```

## Step 3 - Using our new expression

Finally, we'll need to actually put this new predicate to use. Unfortunately, there's no way for us to modify/extend the `#Predicate` macro syntax, short of forking it.

What we can do instead, is to use the `#Predicate` with a `starts(with:)` call to start, e.g.

```swift
let people = [
  "Alice",
  "Alex",
  "Bob",
  "Charlie",
  "Daniel",
].map(Person.init)

let predicate = #Predicate<Person> { person in
  person.name.starts(with: "A")
}
```

We can then use `swift -Xfrontend -dump-macro-expansions predicate_demo.swift` to dump the expansion of that macro:

```swift
Macro expands to:
let predicate = Foundation.Predicate<Person>({ person in
  PredicateExpressions.build_starts(
    PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
      root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(person),
      keyPath: \.name
    ),
    with: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg("A")
  )
})
```

We can then modify the `build_starts` to `build_ends`, to get our final example:

```swift
let predicate = Foundation.Predicate<Person>({ person in
  PredicateExpressions.build_ends( // Replaced `.build_starts(`
    PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
      root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(person),
      keyPath: \.name
    ),
    with: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg("e")
  )
})

let namesEndingWithE = try people.filter(predicate).map(\.name)
print(namesEndingWithE) // ["Alice", "Charlie"]
```

## Step 4 - Lowering to `NSPredicate`

To make this new `CollectionEndsWith` predicate work with SwiftData, CoreData, etc., we'll need to implement the ability to lower it to `NSPredicate`. It could leverage the existing `NSComparisonPredicate.Operator.endsWith`.

Here's what would look like:

```swift
// Adapted from https://github.com/apple/swift-foundation/blob/c4fa869/NSPredicateConversion.swift#L471-L475
extension PredicateExpressions.CollectionEndsWith : ConvertibleExpression where Base.Output : StringProtocol, Suffix.Output : StringProtocol {
  fileprivate func convert(state: inout NSPredicateConversionState) throws -> ExpressionOrPredicate {
    .predicate(NSComparisonPredicate(leftExpression: try base.convertToExpression(state: &state), rightExpression: try suffix.convertToExpression(state: &state), modifier: .direct, type: .endsWith))
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't possible, because it relies on a bunch of private members from `swift-foundation/Sources/FoundationEssentials/Predicate/NSPredicateConversion.swift`, like `ConvertibleExpression`.

Comment: Wow, super-insightful answer!  Can I use perhaps `NSPredicate` when creating a `Query` somehow?

Comment: @GeriBorbás I'm not sure. I would be surprised if there wasn't some kind of escape hatch that just lets you drop to a raw NSPredicate string, but I haven't seen it yet.